# To find the element in the array

Tags: c, arrays

In this code, If I have to find an element '7', it points to the position of array=2,
but how to get the multiple positions, if array has [4,7,7,8,9] then the answer should point the position as array=1 & array=2..

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int i;
 int a[5]={4,5,7,8,9};
 int ele,temp=0,pos=0;
 printf("Enter the element to be search\n");
 scanf("%d",&ele);


 // searching for the element

 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
    a[i]=a[i];
     if (a[i]==ele)
     {
       temp=1;
       pos=i;
     }


  }

   if (temp==1)
   printf("Element found %d , position==%d,",ele,pos);
   else
   printf("Element not found\n");
}
```

Comment: You could put some `printf` inside the loop (i.e. inside the body of your first `if`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int i;
 int a[5]={4,5,7,8,9};
 int found_indices[5]; // array used to store indices of found entries..
 int count = 0; //n entries found;
 int ele;
 printf("Enter the element to be search\n");
 scanf("%d",&ele);


 // searching for the element

 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
     //a[i]=a[i];
     if (a[i]==ele)
     {
       found_indices[count ++] = i; // storing the index of found entry
     }
  }

   if (count!=0) {
       for (i=0; i<count; i++)
           printf("Element found %d , position==%d,", ele, found_indices[i]);
   }
   else
       printf("Element not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your pos variable is just an integer, not an array, so it will store only one value. Instead, make it an array and then store the value of each founded result into the pos array.

Comment: Thank you, can you please describe in more detail in how to collect the resultant values.